# sc.textFile does not work in spark-shell

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

So I am starting to pick up the habit of doing my debugging in spark-shell and I'm running into an issue with collecting from textFile.

I basically have a file with JSON strings in hdfs and when I attempt to do

```
val y = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1/path/to/file.txt").collect()
```

I get the following error:

```
16/05/26 23:51:42 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block broadcast_0 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
16/05/26 23:51:42 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block broadcast_0_piece0 already exists on this machine; not re-adding it
16/05/26 23:51:42 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at QueryAnalyzer.scala:50
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.SerializableWritable
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
```

has anyone run into anything like this before?

Comment: what is rdd type when u read the file

Comment: (val y:RDD[?????]= sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1/path/to/file.txt"))

Comment: I'd imagine that i you don't specify a type scala/spark automatically interpets the type to RDD[String], no?

Comment: RDD[String] is correct type..may i know what spark and hadoop version u using are?

Comment: can u try databrick library for ingest the file

Comment: are you able to run your code on a local file? If so, are you able to access hdfs through the command line client?

Comment: @mark91 I can run the code on a local file just fine, and it also works just fine when I run it in a spark job. For some reason this only happens when I'm in shell mode. I've run into permission issues before, but it seems like they're all fixed when I use HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs

Comment: if you can do the same thing within a spark job, it's rather strange!are you launching that job with some different configuration?i.e. the arguments you pass to the spark-shell are different from the ones you use in your spark-submit?